# Is it acceptable to use a larger gauge wire downstream of a junction box for a deep well pump?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Well pump is some 300 to 400 feet down fed by 10-2 awg wire running into j-box next to the water tank. From the j-box to the main panel is 12-2 awg, 16 ft. Is this acceptable practice?

Comment: What size is the breaker on the well pump circuit?

Comment: Two pole 20 amp.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how much current the pump draws.

If it is less than 20 amps (most likely unless you have an industrial sized well pump) then this is fine and it sounds like they used #10 for the long run to reduce the voltage drop on the circuit.

The higher the current draw the higher the voltage drop on the wire. On long runs of wire we routinely up-size the wire to reduce this voltage drop. This is a very common practice.

Edit: The point raised in the comments is a very good one. #12 wire cannot be on a breaker larger than 20 amps. So, your circuit is limited to 20 amps by the #12 wire.

Comment: Agree funny that they did not run #10 the entire way, must be a small pump 3-400 feet on 10 would have a larger than code 3% drop at that distance around 8-10 amps but I did not do the math based on a recent job where I ended up using a couple of 5 kva transformers to use smaller wire.

Comment: It's entirely possible the 10 ga is there because there was a partial roll in the back of the electrician's truck.

Comment: Normally, the well drillers run the wire to the pump and up to the controller then the electrician takes it from there. That may also be why you ended up with two different size wires.